# Lombok Eclipse issue: "Requesting Java AST from selection"

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, ide, lombok

I have Lombok plugin installed in my Eclipse. It was working fine till now since many days. All of a sudden I am frequently getting a popup in my Eclipse with the following details:

```
An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
lombok/launch/PatchFixesHider$PatchFixes


An internal error occurred during: "Requesting Java AST from selection".
lombok/launch/PatchFixesHider$PatchFixes
```

The Eclipse error log has this:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 2 2016-08-29 13:18:38.631
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.workbench".
!STACK 0
java.lang.LinkageError: lombok/launch/PatchFixesHider$PatchFixes
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.search.OccurrencesFinder.addUsage(OccurrencesFinder.java)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.search.OccurrencesFinder.visit(OccurrencesFinder.java:158)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.QualifiedName.accept0(QualifiedName.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2711)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.acceptChild(ASTNode.java:2759)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.PackageDeclaration.accept0(PackageDeclaration.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2711)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.acceptChild(ASTNode.java:2759)
```

Eclipse version :

```
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Neon Release (4.6.0)
Build id: 20160613-1800
```

This popup is occurring quite frequently and its very annoying.Does anyone knows the solution to fix this?

Comment: `See error log for more details` what does the error log say?

Comment: @ppeterka :  Updated question with error logs.

Comment: What version of Lombok and Eclipse are you using? Seems like some people were able to fix this with an update (see [issue #920](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/920)).

Answer (score 4):

Removed older jar and updated with latest lombok jar (version 1.16.10).. restarted my system. this fixed this issue. Not sure what was the cause of this issue though.

Comment: [This was fixed](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/913) in the latest version of lombok.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, restarting Eclipse was sufficient for me.